# Spring with AspectJ on annoted method leads 404 error

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aspectj, spring-aop

I have the following aspect hadling all REST controllers:

```
@Pointcut(value="execution(* com.company.app.features.*.controller.*.*(..))")
public void controller() { }

@Before("controller()")
public void before(JoinPoint jp) {
    // Log
}
```

That works fine on all methods in the package defined in `@Pointcut` as required.

However when I try to point the `@Before` out to the methods annoted only with `@GetMapping(..)`, the URL is resulting 404 error, however another ones work as usually.

What do I do wrong? Noone of my attempts are working:

- Amended only @Before:   `@Before("method() && @annotation(GetMapping)")`
- Amended only @Pointcut: `@Pointcut(value="execution(@GetMapping com.company...`
- Amended only @Pointcut: `@Pointcut(value="execution(@GetMapping * com.company...`

---

The same result (error 404) is when I implement an interface over the controller class, `@Override` a method annoted with `@GetMapping` and place this method from the interface to the `@Pointcut` as the first piece of code says. I suggest there is a similar thing behind. Would someone explain me?

Comment: before-method should not take an argument Joinpoint

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however not solving my issue.

Comment: The idiomatic way to intercept controller calls is using a [HandlerInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Pointcut(value="execution(* com.company.app.features.*.controller.*.*(..))")
public void controller() { }

@Pointcut(value="execution(@within(org.springframework......GetMapping)")
public void getMapping() { }


@Before("controller() && getMapping(object)")
public void controllerGetMapping(Object objectIfYouNeedIt) {
    // Log
}
```

Comment: You have a typpo in the annotation of `getMapping()` method. I had folowed your idea and finally I have used `@Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping)") ` that works well, so I am about to accept your answer. However, do you know an answer for the 2nd part of my question? :)